# json object conversion into string using python

Tags: jquery, python, json

How to convert JSON object into string using python. Can any one help? I need this object to be converted into string.

```
products = [
    {'id':01,'description':'Hair tonic','price':'$20'},
    {'id':02,'description':'Hair Shampoo','price':'$25'},
    {'id':03,'description':'Hair Comb','price':'$10'},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
json.dumps(products)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html